# TypeScript parent class instance variable return as undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I have two typescript classes named `Member` and another `abstract` class `ComponenetAction`. `ComponentAction` class has Member as instance variable .

```
export abstract class ComponentAction{
public member:Member
constructor(){

}
setMember(member:Member){
    this.member = member;
}
getMember(){
    return this.member;
}}
```

Member class

```
export class Member{
membername:String
isadmine:String
constructor(name:String,admine:String){
    this.membername = name;
    this.isadmine = admine;
}}
```

The `ComponentAction` class is the parent class for my Angular 2 component classes. `LoginComponent` class extends this `ComponentAction` class and set the member during login. That member value is set correctly but while i tried to retrieve the same member from another component class(which also extended `ComponentAction`) am getting 'undefined'.

Login Component

```
export class LoginComponent extends ComponentAction{
isloggedIn:boolean = true;

constructor(private http :Http , private router:Router){
    super();
}
validate(ngform:NgForm){
    console.log('values :'+ngform.value)
    var user = ngform.value.inputEmail ;
    this.http.post('/api/validate/login', {email:ngform.value.inputEmail,password:ngform.value.inputPassword})
    .map(result => result.json())
    .subscribe((result) => {
        this.isloggedIn = result.isvalid;
        let member = new Member(user,result.isadmine);
        super.setMember(member);
        if(this.isloggedIn){
            this.router.navigate(['./dash'])
        }
    })
}
```

}

i tried to get the member information in the `DashboardComponent` am getting it as `undefined`

```
export class DashBoardcomponent extends ComponentAction {
user:string;
private sub: any;
constructor(){
    super();
    console.log('dashboard controller super:'+super.getMember());
}}
```

why the data is not getting after the `router.navigate()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

then `member`   must be a static property in order to be shared with other instances :

```
export abstract class ComponentAction{
static member:Member
constructor(){

}
setMember(member:Member){
    ComponentAction.member = member;
}
getMember(){
    return ComponentAction.member;
}}
```

Comment: thanks it worked , one more question how can i use this member variable in the angular components.means how can i disaplay the member.membername in the DashboardComponent ? while i try member.membername in component Html am getting member a undefined

Comment: you can do this : {{getMember().membername}}