# Typescript child class variables return undefined from parent variables

Tags: angular, typescript

I have tried the solutions and suggestions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43028462/typescript-parent-class-instance-variable-return-as-undefined) (probably duplicated) but can figure out what I'm missing.

I have an `abstract class` called `ParentService` and its `child class` `ChildService` as follows:

`ParentService`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MyModel} from './mymodel-model.service';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export abstract class ParentService {
  constructor() { }
  //the other post suggeted to add 'static' but it doesn´t solve it
  public static word:MyModel = { 
    "AA":"AA",
    "BB":"BB",
  }
}
```

`ChildService`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MyModel} from './mymodel-model.service';
import { ParentService } from './parent.service';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChildService extends ParentService {
  word2:MyModel = {
    "AA":"AA2",
    "BB":"BB2",
  };
}
```

from my `html-component` I can access the `variables` defined in `Childservice` but when trying to read the `variables` from its `ParentService` I get `undefined`

```
{{ child_instance.word2.AA }} // returns 'AA2'
{{ child_instance.word }} // returns undefined
{{ child_instance.word.AA }} // returns error due to undefined "word"
```

Comment: ParentService.word seems to be a static. Could that explain it?

Comment: @ArnovanOordt the other post's solution was to add `static` property to the variable but it doesn't seem to solve it.

Comment: No going to dive too much into the other question, but that answer uses a non-static getter `getMember` to get the static value.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the ParentService.word to be static adding a getter in the child should do the trick:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MyModel} from './mymodel-model.service';
import { ParentService } from './parent.service';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChildService extends ParentService {
  word2:MyModel = {
    "AA":"AA2",
    "BB":"BB2",
  };
  get word3(){
    return ParentService.word;
  }}
}
```

`{{ child_instance.word3.AA }}` should now return 'AA'

Comment: don't need to be `static`. I had implemented the `getter` in child with and without `static`and still getting `undefined `also tried the `getter` in the parent and `undefined` again.

Comment: Then it might have something to do with the way Angular works in this case and you do need `ParentService.word` to be static. In that case the other question/solution should do the trick or you'd need to find another construction/workaround all together.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some digging I have come that Angular (or at least my version 6+) does not "`import`/`include`" `properties` from it `extended class`, more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60100165/angular-6-and-typescript-child-class-extends-from-parent-class-and-banish-child/60100632#60100632)

So the solution will be to literally COPY the `variables`/`function` from the `parent` into the `child` at the very begining (`contructor`), more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60100165/angular-6-and-typescript-child-class-extends-from-parent-class-and-banish-child/60100632#60100632)