# Angular 6 and typescript child class extends from parent class and banish child variables

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have an `abstract class` called `ParentService` and its `child class` `ChildService` as follows:

`ParentService`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MyModel} from './mymodel-model.service';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export abstract class ParentService {
  constructor() { }
  word:MyModel = { 
    "AA":"AA",
    "BB":"BB",
  }
}
```

`ChildService`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MyModel} from './mymodel-model.service';
import { ParentService } from './parent.service';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChildService extends ParentService {
  word2:MyModel = {
    "AA":"AA2",
    "BB":"BB2",
  };
}
```

In the `constructor` of the `app-component` I have declared the child instance as follows:

```
constructor(private child_instance:ChildService){}
```

When printing `child_instance` in the browser console I get:

```
 ParentService {word: {…}}
```

Without the `extends ParentService` I got:

```
 ChildService {word2: {…}}
```

But I need to have both variables in the same class:

```
ChildService {word: {…},word2: {…}}
//or
ParentService {word: {…},word2: {…}}
```

How can I acomplish this?

Comment: Can't you have 2 parameters of child and parent in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

After the clarification of @Satish Pai I have created a work around:

In the `ParentService` class:

```
/* Some code here... */
export class ParentService {
  constructor() { }
  word:Lang = {
    "ES":"ESP",
    "EN":"ENG",
  }
/* Some code here... */
}
```

In the `ChildService` class:

```
/* Some code here... */
export class ChildService{
  constructor(){
    var gParent:ParentService = new ParentService();
    var gkeys = Object.keys(gParent);
    for(var i = 0; i < gkeys.length; i++){
      this[gkeys[i]] = gParent[gkeys[i]];
    }
  }
  /* Some code here... */
}
```

**WARNING:** this will copy the whole `ParentClass` into the `ChildClass` (even functions)

**Suggestion:** You can aply some `regex` over `gkeys` to only copy certain `functions` or `variables`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the `super()` inside your `child.service` constructor.

```
export class ParentService {
  constructor() { }
  word = { 
    "AA":"AA",
    "BB":"BB",
  }
}

export class ChildService extends ParentService {
  word2 = {
    "AA":"AA2",
    "BB":"BB2",
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log(this); // prints ChildService {word: {…}, word2: {…}}
 }
}
```

Comment: `super();` doesn't works for me, still getting `ParentService` variables only.

Comment: @GiancarloBenítez have you tried without abstract keyword in your parent service?

Comment: Open the console and check the log , it should work
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p3mskr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: the `abstract` word yes, I tried also `public` and `static` combinations, nothing. I checked them through console. I know it should... but no luck.